# Electron ipcRenderer message between two windows doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am trying to send a message back from a modal to a browserwindow in order to update it with the data returned from the modal.

The modal has a table where when you click a row, the row id is sent via an ipcRenderer message, but the message doesn't seem to get there, as nothing is logged in the console.

What am I doing wrong?

**Browserwindow (Renderer)**

```
const { remote } = require('electron');
const ipcRenderer = require("electron").ipcRenderer;

function openModal() {
    let win = new remote.BrowserWindow({
        parent: remote.getCurrentWindow(),
        modal: true
    })

    win.webContents.openDevTools();
    var theUrl = 'file://' + __dirname + '/modal.html'

    win.loadURL(theUrl);
}

// Open the modal on button click
document.getElementById("button-search-open")
    .addEventListener("click", () => {
        openModal();
    })

// Log the data received from the modal message
ipcRenderer.on('set-row-active-id', (e, args) => {
    console.log(e, args); // Nothing is logged!
 })
```

**Modal (Renderer)**

```
 var ipcRenderer = require("electron").ipcRenderer;

// Add event listeners to all table rows
document.querySelectorAll('table tr')
    .forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", (e) => { rowClickHandler(e) }));

// Send the row id back to the broserwindow on row click
function rowClickHandler(e) {
    let rowId = e.target.parentElement.dataset.id
    ipcRenderer.send('set-row-active-id', rowId);
}
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://medium.com/@kahlil/how-to-communicate-between-two-electron-windows-166fdbcdc469) can help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ipcRenderer.send`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrenderersendchannel-arg1-arg2-) is used to send message *to Main process*. What you want is sending message to a specific *webContents* by [`contents.send`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentssendchannel-arg1-arg2-)

Since your modal window should send to its parent you can use [`win.getParentWindow`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#wingetparentwindow)

```
// (Modal - Renderer)
const { remote, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
// ...
function rowClickHandler() {
  let rowId = e.target.parentElement.dataset.id
  remote.getCurrentWindow().getParentWindow().send('set-row-active-id', rowId)
}
```

Comment: Riiiiiiiight... it worked! I haven't thought about it this way, thank you for making it click.

Comment: hey, would u mind taking a look at [my very similar question here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53753181/webcontents-send-and-ipcrenderer-on-not-working)